# WiFi Hotspot Software by Facebook Login

Tags: jsp, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I would like to implement a customized WiFi hotstop which needs Facebook Login to enable Internet access for users.  In this scenario a user doesn´t have Internet access before login process is correctly done (although the server hotspot has connection ). In this stage,  users cannot connect directly with Facebook servers, and I’m wondering if there is a way to enable user login against Facebook server before gaining Internet access.

I’m considering these two alternatives:

- To implement a proxy at the server-side for authentication. Users would make the login process through the proxy server, not directly against Facebook servers.  I’ve seen several posts about OAtuh authentication but I  think it's always necessary connection between user and Facebook servers. Am I right? How does it really work?
- Enable the access to IP addresses of Facebook servers at the whitelist of the hotspot controller.  In this case, the user has direct access to Facebook server without authentication. This approach needs updated information about the pool of IP addresses of Facebook servers.  By doing some tests I could check that  these IP address are dynamic, so my doubt is if there a way to automatically discover the range of IPs associated to Facebook servers so I could include all of them in the mentioned whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

You would need domain based walled garden really as otherwise you will fall fowl of changes to the IP ranges used by Facebook as you have outlined, the equipment used will dictate whether this is possible.

Have you seen http://www.purplewifi.net, there is a free version there if it is for deployment